# ggplot2 coord_sf when use crs = 4326 or label parameter in scale_x_continuous ,can not show right

Tags: r, ggplot2

When i use the following code,x axis only show -180 and 180.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(magrittr)
library(sf)


your_raster <- raster::raster("wc2.1_2.5m_elev.tif")
raster_df <- raster::as.data.frame(your_raster, xy = TRUE) %>% 
  na.omit()


ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = raster_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = wc2.1_2.5m_elev))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(9,"Greys")#[c(4,5,7,8,9)]
  )+
  # coord_sf(expand = F,crs = 4326) +
  coord_sf(expand = F,xlim = c(-180, 180),crs = 4326)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -180, to = 180, by = 20))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -80, to = 80, by = 20))
```

[image]

when i drop `crs = 4326` ,it can show right as follow:
[image]

but I want the "°S" and "°N".

So  i try use `labels`  in `scale_y_continuous`

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = raster_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = wc2.1_2.5m_elev))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(9,"Greys")#[c(4,5,7,8,9)]
  )+
  # coord_sf(expand = F,crs = 4326) +
  coord_sf(expand = F,xlim = c(-180, 180)#,crs = st_crs(4326)
           )+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -180, to = 180, by = 20)
                     # ,labels =1:19
                     ,labels = c("180°", "160°W", "140°W", "120°W", "100°W","80°W", "60°W", "40°W", "20°W","0°"
                                 ,"20°E", "40°E", "60°E", "80°E","100°E","120°E", "140°E", "160°E", "180°")

                     )+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -80, to = 80, by = 20)
                     ,labels = c("80°S", "60°S", "40°S", "20°S","0",
                                 "20°N", "40°N", "60°N", "80°N")
                     )
```

y axis is ok,but x axis error .
[image]

you can get the data from https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html
[image]

Comment: I am guessing it could be because the "180°" label is repeated in the x-axis. Can you try "180°W" and "180°E" instead?

Comment: @Sys_Tem thanks, i tried and  it just do not work ,you can see i used label =1:19(commented), but failed.

Comment: st_graticule() looks as though it designed for cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using coord_sf(expand = T) instead of F will include the limits of the x-axis and make the length of the breaks equal to the labels (which is 19).

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = raster_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = wc2.1_2.5m_elev))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(9,"Greys")#[c(4,5,7,8,9)]
  )+
  # coord_sf(expand = F,crs = 4326) +
  coord_sf(expand = T,xlim = c(-180, 180)#,crs = st_crs(4326)
  )+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-180, 180, by = 20), 
                     #,labels =1:19
                     labels = c("180", "160°W", "140°W", "120°W", "100°W","80°W", "60°W", "40°W", "20°W","0°"
                                 ,"20°E", "40°E", "60°E", "80°E","100°E","120°E", "140°E", "160°E", "180")
  )+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -80, to = 80, by = 20)
                     ,labels = c("80°S", "60°S", "40°S", "20°S","0",
                                 "20°N", "40°N", "60°N", "80°N")
  )
```

Result:

[image]

Also, your initial code seems to work, at least for me except it does not show the limits (-180°W and 180°E):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = raster_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = wc2.1_2.5m_elev))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(9,"Greys")#[c(4,5,7,8,9)]
  )+
  # coord_sf(expand = F,crs = 4326) +
  coord_sf(expand = F,xlim = c(-180, 180),crs = 4326)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -180, to = 180, by = 20))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -80, to = 80, by = 20))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks ，I find the reason why  my initial code  can not  work, it's my R version is too old(4.1.3).